# Projection of a "matrix"

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

let $\mathcal{S}$ be a vectorspace of $3\times 3$ matrices defined as

$\mathcal{S}=\{\mathbf{F} \in \mathcal{S} \hspace{2mm} s.t \hspace{2mm} f_{i,j}\in\mathbb{R}\hspace{2mm} 1\leq i,j \leq 3\}$

Let $\mathcal{S^{*}}$ be a another vectorspace of $2\times 2$ matrices defined as

$\mathcal{S^{*}}=\{\mathbf{G} \in \mathcal{S^{*}} \hspace{2mm} s.t \hspace{2mm} g_{p,q}\in\mathbb{R}\hspace{2mm} 1\leq p,q \leq 2\}$

Given that $\mathbf{X}\in\mathcal{S}$, how can I find its "closest" approximation in $\mathcal{S^{*}}$.

Incase of vectors I know that answer is by using "orthogonal projection". But I don't know what is meant by taking **"orthogonal projection of matrices"**

Moreover if someone is aware of any text/paper that can be helpful in learning about **"vector spaces of matrices"**, please make a reference

Comment: What exactly is $\mathbf F$ supposed to be?  The complex numbers?

Comment: Thats just a name. I am talking about real matrices. Let me change that to R

Comment: First, the "definitions" of $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{S^*}$ are not definitions: they are self-referencing (as if I define _zorglub_ by saying that anything _zorglub_ is _zorglub_: it's not a definition). 

Then, a matrix represents, in a given basis, an application which maps a vector to another vector. There is an operator which maps any matrix of  $\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ and any vector of $\mathbb{R}^3$ to a vector of $\mathbb{R}^3$. In your case, you need an operator between 3-by-3 matrices and 2-by-2 matrices. Maybe you're interested in _tensor projection_?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I edited those definitions. I hope they make sense now

Comment: To define "closest" you need a distance metric on your space of matrices. When are two matrices close? The projection strategy for vectors also works only once a metric has been established.

Comment: That right....I am working in euclidean space so if I define distance metric as 2-norm of difference $\mathbf{X-X^{*}}$ where $\mathbf{ X^{*} \in \mathcal{S}^{*}}$

Comment: Your set definitions still make no sense

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom ..... How should I write that $\mathcal{S}$ is a set of all  $3\times 3$ real matrices denoted as $\mathbf{F}$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to well understand your question. But, a $3\times 3$ matrix with real entries  can be seen as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^9$, e.g. as:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\
a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}
\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}\\a_{12}\\a_{13}\\a_{21}\\a_{22}\\a_{23}\\
a_{31}\\a_{32}\\a_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
In the same way your $S^*$ is isomorpic to a subspace of dimension $4$ of $\mathbb{R}^9$. If you know what subspace you want ( there are infinitely many) you can orthogonally project any vector that represents a matrix of $M_3(\mathbb{R})$ on this subspace.

If you are interested to the more complex question of dimensionality reduction of data tensors, you can start from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_subspace_learning).